# How to put a Hyphen in column Total Cost Value in power bi

Tags: powerbi

I have a table with blank value, but i want a hyphen "-" to appear when the value is null.
Using an expression similar to this:

var VLGROUP =
(Expression……
RETURN
IF(
ISBLANK(VLGROUP),
BLANK(),
VLGROUP)

Someone know if is possible?
Thanks!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.im)

[image]gur.com/C0u8s.png

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this below option-

```
Sales for the Group = 

var sales =
    CALCULATE( 
        SUM(Financialcostcenter[amount]), 
        Financialcostcenter[partnercompany]= "BRE", 
        Financialcostcenter[2 digits]=71, 
        DATESYTD('Datas'[Date])
    ) 
    + 
    CALCULATE( 
        SUM(Financialcostcenter[amount]), 
        Financialcostcenter[partnercompany]= "GRM", 
        Financialcostcenter[2 digits]=71, 
        DATESYTD('Datas'[Date])
    ) 


RETURN IF(sales = BLANK(),"-", -(sales))
```

Comment: It doesn't work.
The error says  
  -> It is not possible to convert the "-" value from the Text type to the Numeric / Date type.

Comment: @MarianaPedroso, check now, I have added a conversion.

Comment: Sales for the Group = 

var VLGROUP=
-(CALCULATE(SUM(Financialcostcenter[amount]),
Financialcostcenter[partnercompany]= "BRE",
Financialcostcenter[2 digits]=71
DATESYTD('Datas'[Date]))
+
CALCULATE(
SUM(Financialcostcenter[amount]),
Financialcostcenter[partnercompany]= "GRM",
Financialcostcenter[2 digits]=71
DATESYTD('Datas'[Date]))
)
RETURN 
IF(VLGROUP = BLANK(), "-", CONVERT(VLGROUP, STRING))

Comment: You can see better on the image i put, where i asked the question.

Comment: There is no issue with the last line - RETURN IF(VLGROUP = BLANK(), "-", CONVERT(VLGROUP, STRING)). Even the code without conversion was correct as well.

Comment: You have issue in CALCULATION part. 1) why no comma is not there between code - "Financialcostcenter[2 digits]=71 DATESYTD('Datas'[Date])"? 2) Check the data type of column - "Financialcostcenter[amount]". If it is text, change the type as number.

Comment: Also need to check the data type of - Financialcostcenter[2 digits]. If that is a string, the condition will be ->>  Financialcostcenter[2 digits]= "71"

Comment: The measure is working whithout the commas. If i just put the part 1 and take out the "var vlgroup" and  the "return..." it works perfectly.  I don't understand why ins't work when i put all together.

Comment: This measure is working right now:

Sales for the Group = 
-(CALCULATE(
SUM(Financialcostcenter[amount]),
Financialcostcenter[partnercompany]= "BRE",
Financialcostcenter[2 digits]=71,
DATESYTD('Datas'[Date]))
+
CALCULATE(
SUM(Financialcostcenter[amount]),
Financialcostcenter[partnercompany]= "GRM",
Financialcostcenter[2 digits]=71,
DATESYTD('Datas'[Date]))
)

Comment: @MarianaPedroso, can you check the updated answer? if your last given code works, there is no reason for the given answer to not work.